# How to attach file with selenium test

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a browse file button. When i am trying to attach file, selenium does not interact with file's dialog window.

- I tried this method but it's not working for my test.
  http://cheryjose.blogspot.com.tr/2013/03/how-to-interact-with-dialog-windows.html
- and this [Selenium WebDriver and browsers select file dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851051/selenium-webdriver-and-browsers-select-file-dialog)

How can i interact with dialog page or set file path to input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. I create input with bootstrap and input was hidden. Before run test i execute this code;

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = Browser as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("return $('input').show()");
```

this javascript code ensure input elements' remove hidden attributes. So run this code and send path to input;

```
driver.findElement(By.id("myUploadElement")).sendKeys("<PathToMyFile>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes sendkeys method does not work
especially,  when we have file upload without using input tag.
you can consider using autoit for this.

Autoit will help you to choose a file in file browser.

Your code  should be like :-

Click on browse button.
call a cmd executable in your code (which will execute your autoit code and will select a file).
and then, continue with normal execution.

If require, I can post my auto it script here, but will after 2-3 days as I don't have access to my system during this period.